# Row-by-row directly-standardised rate

Tags: r

I am using dsrTest to calculate the directly-standardised rate and confidence intervals for some data I have. Example below:

| Year | Sex | Count | Population | StPop |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2020 | M | 200 | 1000 | 5500 |
| 2020 | F | 300 | 1000 | 5500 |
| 2020 | M | 150 | 1000 | 5500 |
| 2020 | F | 400 | 1000 | 5500 |

I use this, which does work, but only on one row at a time, or it seems to gather the entire dataset!

```
dsrTest(df$Count,df$Population,df$StPop,null.value = NULL,alternative = c("two.sided"),conf.level = 0.95,mult = 1,method = c("dobson"),control = list())
```

This results in a list with directly-standardised rate and the confidence intervals I need, but I would like to be able to create a table with the following layout, by applying that DSR to each row:

| Year | Sex | Count | Population | StPop | DSR | LCI | UCI |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2020 | M | 200 | 1000 | 5500 | x | x | x |
| 2020 | F | 300 | 1000 | 5500 | x | x | x |
| 2020 | M | 150 | 1000 | 5500 | x | x | x |
| 2020 | F | 400 | 1000 | 5500 | x | x | x |

However, I am a bit stuck with how to actually do that. I did try  `apply()` but I am not skilled enough to get it to work and I keep getting "Error: Unexpected input".

Thank you very much in advance.